# Div is ignoring css

Tags: html, css

The following css code does NOT center the `#wrapper` div:

```
#wrapper{
    width:1000px;
    height:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url('../img/background2.jpg');
}
```

I have already done this a couple of times. Thats why I dont understand why it's not working.

The html is quite simple.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">...</div>
</body>
```

Is somebody there with an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Yup it does](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/htq6F/) - Also make sure you do not have another element using the id `wrapper`.

Comment: Add `background-position:center;` to your css. Your image might not be as large as the backgound div looking like it does not center properly

Comment: Also check your image path is correct (right-click on the element in Chrome/Firefox and click Inspect Element).

Comment: @RickHoving The image shouldn't matter as the OP does not have `no-repeat` set so they would notice that. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/htq6F/1/)

Comment: * wrapper is declared only once, image is correct, the image size is also 1000x800 - maybe there is the problem?

Comment: @wurmi As you can see from as examples, the code works fine. Maybe you have other code that is affecting this. Also are you seeing the image at all? If not use `outline: 1px solid;` to see where the `div` is (if it is there at all). If you do see the outline then you know its a problem with the image link.

Comment: the output is fine so far. only the centering issue is bothering me

Comment: @wurmi Then you have other code that is affecting it I guess. Because as I said before the code you rpovided works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your body tag also has the following css:

```
body {
    width:100%;
}
```

Otherwise the div doesn't know what margins to set on the left and right.
If your html does not contain the html tags, doctype etc. it might also not work, make sure you're using these accordingly.

Comment: Huh? What are you talking about? You have seen by our examples that it works. Why would this need to define the height on the body as `100%`?

Comment: @wurmi I am curious as to how this solved the problem. Could you provide more code so I can see where you went wrong.

Comment: There is no need to set the height to 100% to solve this problem, by setting the height to 100% you may be suspect to further problems in your code later down the line.

Comment: True, but it solves future problems ;), I removed it since it seems to cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in your CSS:

```
html, 
body { 
  width:100%; 
}
```